# Correspondence between two tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join

I have table
the table code_Commune contains gps for the city in general
code_Commune:

```
Code_commune           Nom_commune          coordonnees_gps
01263                MONTMERLE SUR SAONE             46.0849573236,4.7608579486
```

Now I need to do correspondence with the `table lead` to add code_commune and Nom_Commune:

Table lead

```
Id_lead     latitude     Longitude   
F439130C    46.00000000  6.39522000  
24A09223    46.00000000  6.39522000  
42899ABF    46.00000000  4.75212800
```

Is there any way to do correspondence between the two tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the closest city using some sort of distance measure.  First, fix your first table:

```
alter table code_commune
    add latitude as (convert(decimal(14,10), 
                             left(coordonnees_gps, charindex(',', coordonnees_gps) - 1)
                            )
                    );

alter table code_commune
    add longitude as (convert(decimal(14,10), 
                              stuff(coordonnees_gps, 1, charindex(',', coordonnees_gps), '')
                             )
                     );
```

Then you can use `apply`, once you decide on a distance metric.  The following uses Manhattan distance:

```
select l.*, cc.code_comune
from leads l outer apply
     (select top (1) cc.*
      from code_commune cc
      order by abs(cc.latitude - l.latitude) + abs(cc.longitude - l.longitude)
     );
```

This is *highly* inefficient.  If you need efficiency, then you should be looking into [SQL Server's support for spatial data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/spatial/spatial-data-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: It took too much time. I don't understand how to optimize it.